# How can I include id and name attributes in @Model.Value in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am displaying a simple model value in view page as : `@Model.Name`
and I need to include an id and a name in it.

I can include id and name in Html.TextBoxFor as :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control bg-white", @placeholder = "Name", @id="Name", @name="Name" })
```

Similarly I need id and name in `@Model.Name` as well .
Can anyone Help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using `TextBoxFor`, no need to give `@name` HTML attribute because the helper assign it automatically for you. Why you want to use `id` and `name` HTML attributes if you just want to display it, because `name` attribute used when submitting the form?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to include an Id and a name in it? @Model.Name will just spit out the value of that property which is I assume a string. Could you provide an example of the end result HTML you are looking to achieve?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto there are other fields as well in the view, and when i submit those field values, i need the "Name" value as well.

Comment: @JonRyan I need the alternative syntax for `@Model.Name` where I can include id and name attributes.

Comment: You need to wrap it inside `<input>` element to include the property for submission. The `TextBoxFor` helper renders an input element like this: `<input id="Name" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it's not an input type. it's just a value that I'm displaying from viewmodel.

Comment: Sorry @Shiwa that didn’t really answer my question. The only alternative syntax I can think of to display the value of Name is @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name) but all that will do is give you the value for that field achieving the same result. Could you please provide some example HTML of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the same result using:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Name", name = "Name" }})

i think this can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I didn't find the answer I was looking for and hence, I used an alternative way to send my 'Name' value as follows :

```
    @Model.Name
<input type="text" name="name" value="@Model.Name" hidden />
```

I created an input type and made it hidden so that I can later(while submitting form) extract value via name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change name of property.
I can't get id attribute with "CaseNumber", but I get it rename property to "CrimeNumber".

Answer (score 0):

### ASP.NET Core HTML Attributes needed for Posting Forms

Some people do not use ASP.NET CORE "`Tag Helpers`" when building ASP.NET pages, but still need to post data that bind to models on the server.

It took me some time to figure out the *magic HTML attribute names* needed for ASP.NET .NET 7 Core for MVC Views or Razor Pages to bind your HTML forms to *models* in your controller. This is for people that prefer to use their own clean HTML rather that ASP.NET's helper versions which generate the ID and NAME identifiers. For validation I still recommend you use `asp-for` and their validation tag helpers. But the designs below will help you get control over what Microsoft is actually doing to your HTML form fields, so if you avoid them you can still communicate and bind with the models on the server.

If your View Page and matching Controller Method is using a model class representing **one record**, use this example below. Do not forget to send the `value` attribute with the `name` attribute in order to complete the `name-value` pair in the body of the Request. Notice below the `value` attribute is assigned to the `@Model` objects property value, but the `id` and `name` just need the `raw string name` of the property:

```
<input type="text" 
id="YourModelPropertyName" 
name="YourModelPropertyName" 
value="@Model.YourModelPropertyName"/>
```

...for example...

```
My Model:
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

My Server Controller Method:
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public string MyFormProcessor([FromForm] Person model){
    return model.FirstName;
}

My Form Field:
<input type="text" 
id="FirstName" <<< ALERT: This must match your Models property name!
name="FirstName" 
value="@Model.FirstName" />
```

...or if your server Model is *complex* and your HTML form is returning a `List<Person>` holding many child objects, use this naming convention...

```
public class Business
{
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}


@model Business
@{
    var i = 0;
}
@foreach(var item in @Model.Employees )
{
    <input type="text" 
    id="Person[@i].FirstName" 
    name="Person[@i].FirstName" 
    value="@item.FirstName" />
    i++;
}
```

ASP.NET Core on the server side will then recognize your html form and the name-value pair and bind your model easily to the name fields. In the past Microsoft used underscores and strange numbering schemes to translate model and property/member names into HTML text names needed to bind to their model data on the server. They seem to have changed that design, yet again...

You ONLY need to worry about the "matching" property name issue other posters are talking about if your server controller method is trying to just extract a single form field value from the form field name-value list sent to the server. That is done using this design:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public string MyFormProcessor([FromForm] string myformfieldname){
    return myformfieldname;
}
```

HTML "BEST PRACTICES" ADVICE

**Btw...always assign your `id` and `name` attributes the same value** when working with HTML forms, even though the `name` is the only value sent to the server with the form. It makes it easy to keep `id` unique and traceable in complex HTML forms.